# GWT Obfuscation crashes iPad Safari browser

Tags: ipad, gwt, mobile-safari

I built a large GWT app that works fine on chrome/safari. But on the iPad 2 the app crashes mobile safari.

I suspect that the obfuscation version that the compiler creates, output lines that are too long for the iPad 2 WebKit browser. When I compile the app in pretty mode it works.

Does anyone has any hints on how to solve this problem? going to production with pretty mode is not an option.

Thanks!

Comment: This looks like a bug. You should post this on gwt group and/or submit a bug report.

Answer (score 2):

We had the same issue and it seems to be a problem with iOS 4.x. The fix for this it to compile in PRETTY mode, that will work

Answer (score 1):

i ran into the same issue with ipad one and a large gwt app. I changed from the iframe gwt linker to the cross site javascript linker and got rid of the issue.

In your gwt.xml file try this:

```
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.core.Core" />
<add-linker name="xs" />
```